# Project a collection as task and wait for all completion

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to parallelize work issued from a collection, and wait for the completion of all tasks.

Here is basically what I have:

```
public Task<int> DoWorkAsync(int arg){

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return arg*2;
    });

}


public async void DoAllWorks(){
    ICollection<int> workToDo = GetSomeWorkFromSomewhere();

    IEnumerable<Task<int>> tasks = workToDo.Select(i=> DoWorkAsync(i));


    int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Debug.Write(results.Sum()); // Never called
}


public void Main(){
    DoAllWorks();

    // rest of code, which is called
    OtherMethods();

}
```

However, the `WhenAll` method immediately exits and the rest of the code runs, even if there is still work executing.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `async void` which should only be used for event handlers.

When you use `async void` you can't wait for the `async` operation to complete (synchronously or asynchronously). That means it "fires" `DoAllWorks` and moves on as it can't know when `DoAllWorks` completes. `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` inside `DoAllWorks` waits just fine, but the calling method already moved on.

You should return a task instead that you can `await` or `Wait()` in this case as `Main` can't be `async` itself.

```
public void Main()
{
    DoAllWorks().Wait();
    // rest of code, which is called
    OtherMethods();
}

public async Task DoAllWorks()
{
    ICollection<int> workToDo = GetSomeWorkFromSomewhere();
    IEnumerable<Task<int>> tasks = workToDo.Select(i=> DoWorkAsync(i));
    int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Debug.Write(results.Sum());
}
```

Comment: thanks... I replaced my code with something like: `var allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks);    allTasks.Wait();     int[] result = allTasks.Result;` and that solved the issue.

Comment: @SteveB That would do it too but it's not `async`, so you can just use `Task.WaitAll` instead. However I would recommend keeping everything asynchronous if you can and only block inside `Main`.

Comment: this is for a one time data migration batch... I can leave with non optimal code

Comment: anyways, thanks for the explanation. Next time i'll have to write async code, I'll try to follow your advise regarding blocking only in main

Answer (score 0):

You should not use async void except for event handlers. If you return a Task you can than await on it in the main method with `await` keyword or like that  :

`DoAllWorks().Wait();`

Just for information you don't need to use `Thread.Sleep(1000);`. You could rewrite your code a little to be more consistent with `async/await` construct

```
return Task.Run(async ()=> {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return arg*2;
});
```